# jdk 1.7 + tomcat 7 + running a batch process

Tags: java, tomcat7, java-7, batch-processing

I ported a Java web application which used JDK 1.5 and ran under Tomcat 5.5 to now use JDK 1.7 and running under Tomcat 7. I am tasked with developing a Java batch program that will be scheduled. Many of the classes used by the batch process are also used by the web app as well.

Ten years ago I wrote a batch process to use concurrent scheduler. What are some ways today to implement a scheduled batch process using the environment I mentioned above?

**Edit:**
It has been suggested that I use quartz or ScheduledExecutorService. After taking a look at both of those solutions, I think they may provide more than what I need. At the moment, there exists a batch process that is basically a Java program scheduled to run as a Windows NT Server scheduled task and this approach works well enough for the existing batch process. The new batch process that I will develop can follow this approach as well but next I have a deployment question. The .class files and the .properties and the .jar files used by the batch process are in a separate folder from the web application in webapps. What I need is an automated deployment strategy for the batch processes only. I will mark my original question as answered and ask a new question about the deployment.

Comment: [quartz-scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) if you want too much flexibility or [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Quartz is made for this job:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.5/reference/scheduling.html